# How to add floating `NSView` to NSWindow as done in Safari

Tags: cocoa

In Safari, when mouse pointer is moved towards left extreme of screen, a floating bookmark view comes sliding out. Is that a `NSView` or `NSWindow`.

Here is the screenshot.
[image: Here is the screenshot]

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the new `NSplitViewController` added in OS X 10.10

You can choose between three different styles for each of the `splitViewItems` inside this controller.

The sidebar style adds the typical blurred background and the behavior of being able to collapse. In addition you get the neat hover effect when it is collapsed.